# data.d does not return any data and says undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

trying to retrieve data from data.d but not able to access data from data.d as it says data.d is undefined

this is my jquery function

```
$("body").on("click", "#aProfile", function () {
    $("#divProfile").show();
    $("#divChangePassword").hide();
    $("#txtProfileUserName").val('<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString()%>').prop('disabled', true);
    var UserName = $("#txtProfileUserName").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "StudentPanel.aspx/GetUserDetails",
        data: JSON.stringify({ UserName: $('#txtProfileUserName').val() }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(data.d);
            $('#txtProfileName').val(data.d.Name);
            $('#txtProfileEmail').val(data.d.Email);
            $('#txtProfileGender').val(data.d.Gender);
            $('#txtProfileContact').val(data.d.Contact);
            $('#txtProfileCountry').val(data.d.Country);
            $('#txtProfileState').val(data.d.State);
            $('#txtProfileCity').val(data.d.City);
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });
    $('#txtProfileCountry').prop('visible', false);
    $(".Profile").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

this is my c# function

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static User GetUserDetails(string UserName){
    User u = new User();
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)){
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetSISUserByName",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@UserName",
            Value = UserName
        });
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            u.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
            u.UserName = UserName;
            u.Email = dr["Email"].ToString();
            u.Gender = dr["Gender"].ToString();
            u.Contact = dr["Contact"].ToString();
            u.Country = dr["Country"].ToString();
            u.State = dr["State"].ToString();
            u.City = dr["City"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return u;
}
```

I want to assign value from data.d but it returns undefined data.d

Comment: can you alert(data)?

Comment: Don't you have to print `u` in the function?

Comment: tried using data.name but same error data.name is undefined

Comment: try `console.log(data)` and check the console.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch i tried to alert data and it says [object Object]

Comment: @Vaishak no i dont have to print u in function, im just returning data in the u object

Comment: There's no `d` in `u`? What are you trying to do, and where did you get `d` from?

Comment: @BrijeshBhakta try this alert(data.User.Name);

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan i did log the data and it respong "{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"
}"

Comment: @lc. the data returned from JSON file is in the form of 

{
d:
{
Name: "Value"
}
}

Comment: @Dr.Stitch I tried alert(data.User.Name) and it alerted the same undefined

Comment: so, are you getting any value for `data.Message`? That means there is some error in the C# function.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan I checked the function and it seem to be working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved

Inside ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs I changd :

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

To:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

or you can just comment the line and its done